# Incompatible libpng version in application and library

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, shared-libraries, gdal, libpng

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04, on which I compile and run our software that requires `libpng` and `libQtGUI`, without a problem.

But two days ago, I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a new virtual machine. Compilation is going well, but when I want to run our soft, I get the message:

```
libpng warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.4.4
libpng warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.2.51
libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library
```

If I set `LD_PRELOAD` to load libpng-1.4.4, the message is the opposite :

```
libpng warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.2.50
libpng warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.4.4
libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library
```

(Anyway, `LD_PRELOAD` is not set on my 14.04 and it works fine). If I run `ldd` on my soft, it shows that only `libQtGui` requires `libpng12.so` (if I am on 14.04 or 15.10).

How can I resolve this problem, without recompile `libQtGui` since it wasn't required on my 14.04 VM?

EDIT: it seems to work fine if I don't link with `libgdal`, that is strange because according to ldd, `libgdal` is not related to `libpng`...